# optional int(request.POST.get('timeout') throws error when empty

Tags: django, django-forms

This field `timeout = int(request.POST.get('timeout'))` throws an error saying
`invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

this is my model field:  `timeout = models.IntegerField(default=10)`
The forms submits just fine if I submit number because the form interprets it as a string but my form handler will convert it into integer. But it fails if I leave the field blank. Seems like it can't process an empty string.

What can I do ?

forms.py:

```
class TestCaseSuiteForm(forms.ModelForm):

    name                = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                    'class': 'form-control',
                                    'placeholder': 'Enter Name'}), label='')
    documentation       = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                    'class': 'form-control',
                                    'placeholder': 'Enter Documentation'}), label='')
    setup               = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                    'class': 'form-control',
                                    'placeholder': 'Enter Setup'}), label='')
    teardown            = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                    'class': 'form-control',
                                    'placeholder': 'Enter teardown'}), label='')
    force_tags          = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                    'class': 'form-control',
                                    'placeholder': 'Enter Force Tags'}), label='')
    timeout             = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                    'class': 'form-control',
                                    'placeholder': 'Enter Timeout (optional)'}),
                                    required=False, label='')
    class Meta:
        model = TestCase
        fields = [
        'name',
        'documentation',
        'force_tags',
        'setup',
        'teardown',
        'timeout',
    ]
```

my view:

```
def index(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_tc = TestCaseForm(request.POST)
        form_ts = TestCaseSuiteForm(request.POST)
        if form_tc.is_valid() or form_ts.is_valid():
            form_tc.save()
            form_ts.save()
            return redirect('/list')
```

In case you're wondering ... I've got two forms using one submit button.

Comment: if request.POST.get('timeout') is None then it will give error

Comment: Please could you post the form you are using ? to avoid a quick and dirty answer

Comment: @PRMoureu   Foms.py added.

Comment: You need to show your view. If you are using `request.POST.get...`, then you don't actually seem to be using the form at all.

Comment: Added my view for review.

Answer (score 1):

Having gone to the trouble of defining a form and validating it, you are supposed to use that validated data, rather than resorting to the raw post data. Not only will the validated data use defaults as defined in the form where necessary, it will also convert types etc.

```
if form_tc.is_valid() and form_ts.is_valid():
    TestCase.objects.create(
        name=form.cleaned_data['name'],
        documentation=cleaned_data['documentation'],
        ...
    )
```

Note, you need to use the unprefixed field names as the keys here.

But this still isn't really getting you what you want. You haven't defined all your model fields as form fields, so you won't get defaults for the fields you haven't defined. Instead you should be using a *model form*.

```
class TestCaseSuiteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TestCase
        fields = ['name', 'documentation', ...]
```

and now in your view you simply save the form to create the objects:

```
if form_tc.is_valid() and form_ts.is_valid():
    form_tc.save()
    form_ts.save()
```

Now your model defaults will be used appropriately.

Comment: Just a note here. You don't need to call `.save()` with `model.objects.create()` as this syntax calls `.save()` for you.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that you do. `form.save()` is an alternative to `Model.objects.create(**form.cleaned_data)`.

Comment: Hi Daniel. I tried to follow your advice and used `cleaned_data` which I was supposed to use anyway. However on line `timeout = form.cleaned_data['timeout']` as well as `timeout = form.cleaned_data.get('timeout')` I get `NOT NULL constraint failed: frontend_testcase.timeout` which still shows that the attribute `default=10` in model field isn't actually doing anything.

Comment: You didn't set a default in your definition of the form field. But as I said, the better approach is to use a model form and just call form.save().

Comment: Please review the code I updated to reflect the changes you suggested. At the moment nothing is being validated and all data is being discarded not just the `timeout` field. (form validation is real fun in Django)

Answer (score 0):

Set a default using:

```
timeout = int(request.POST.get('timeout', 0))
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. However I'd like to use the default 10 as defined in models if the field is left blank. Your suggestion will insert 0 if the field is left blank.

Comment: Yes, just change the 0 for whatever default value you want. In your case, 10.

Comment: I thought it's kinda redundant to be passing the same value into database from two different places but it may be the only way to get around the error. Will give it a go.

Comment: Keep throwing the same error which is pretty strange since all Python tuts are saying that you can retrieve default value from dictionary with `get` specifying the second argument with the desired default value if there's no value to begin with.

Comment: If you're worried about redundancy, then set a TIMEOUT in your config and import that wherever you need it, rather than hardcoding 10. As to why they doesn't work, I don't know - it should. Seems like there's another issue somewhere.